# Looking for Scid's opening book viewer

Tags: database, file, chess, bin

I'm trying to implement a chess bot using an opening library.

I've downloaded an opening book file (opening.bin) from [Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/).

Is there a viewer utility available for download ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for answering the question late. Basically, you should use polyglot for opening the .bin file. The .bin format is a format invented by Polyglot's author, and it makes sense to use his code to open it. Take a look of polyglot's source, book.cpp, it has everything you need even selecting a random move. Alternatively, you could study the source code for Fruit and Stockfish, both chess engines use the .bin opening books.

In general, don't ask chess questions on stackoverflow, ask on talkchess.com.